# Type Error for Context Bounding with Priority Implicits

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, context-bound

I have the following issue, and I am confused as to what is going:

1. I have a priority implicit defined
2. I use this priority implicit to impose a context bound
3. I declare a case class with a default field, which has values that are covered by the context bound
4. I am still getting a type error

A minimal working example which reflects the actual code I am working on. I basically need the priority implicits in other part of my code:

```
    // priority implicits
    sealed trait Stringifier[T] {
      def stringify(lst: List[T]): String
    }
    
    trait Int_Stringifier {
      implicit object IntStringifier {
        def stringify(lst: List[Int]): String = lst.toString()
      }
    }
    
    object Double_Stringifier extends Int_Stringifier {
      implicit object DoubleStringifier extends Stringifier[Double] {
        def stringify(lst: List[Double]): String = lst.toString()
      }
    }
    
    object Example extends App {
    
      trait Animal[T0] {
        def incrementAge(): Animal[T0]
      }
    
      case class Dog[T0: Stringifier]
      (age: Int = 0, locations: List[T0] = List(1, 2, 3)) extends Animal[String] {
        def incrementAge(): Dog[T0] = this.copy(age = age + 1)
      }
    }
 val t = Dog(age = 100)
```

I get a type mismatch error:

```
required List[T0]

found List[Int]
```

What is going on here? I reasoned that since I am creating my default parameters within the bound, the type should match. Am I missing some trick here to make this work?

Comment: Thanks, I need to have some sort of default value there as other parts of the code use the default constructor. I know I can remove the default value and make it work but that would require changing a very large code base. Is there a way to get the default val to work here or somehow provide evidence?

Comment: @finite_diffidence Your code is not [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because it compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/W4jDvvnjSIu1JwSvw3yJrA
How to reproduce your compile error?

Comment: Apologies Dmytro, it seems my IDE was showing an error on screen, I added a line in the example, but it throws a different error about implicits not being found - I think the error is directly related to not being able to provide evidence.

Comment: @user *What if someone expects locations to be a List[String]?* This will be a compile error on call site, not on definition site.

Comment: @user *You might be able to use `implicitly[List[T0]]` and provide implicit values of `List[Int]`, etc.* Implicits of standard types like `List[...]` is reallly a bad idea.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I didn't mean that `implicitly[List[T0]]` was a good solution, just that you could use it as a band aid. I didn't know you could provide default arguments like that, though. I've removed my comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how to reproduce your compile error

```
required List[T0]

found List[Int]
```

The code you added

```
val t = Dog(age = 100)
```

produces a different error

```
Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type App.Stringifier[Int]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
    val t = Dog(age = 100)
```

This is because you missed `extends Stringifier[Int]` and `import Double_Stringifier._`

```
trait Int_Stringifier {
  implicit object IntStringifier extends Stringifier[Int] {
    def stringify(lst: List[Int]): String = lst.toString()
  }
}

import Double_Stringifier._

val t = Dog(age = 100) // compiles
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro, Ill have to go back to my code and revisit - the IDE still shows an error on my side when I make your changes, but the code does indeed compile. I think it may be something up with my IntelliJ, but I will take a look.

Comment: @finite_diffidence Actually for me IntelliJ 2020.1.3 shows type mismatch too. This is false reporting of compile error.